# Wave equation - three questions

Tags: waves, differential-equations

there are three question that I've never thought about the homogeneous wave Equation.

1. For the Cylindrical wave, [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/cylindrical-wave#:%7E:text=In%20a%20monochromatic%20wave%20%CF%95,function%20of%20the%20first%20kind.) it is possible to find the derivation (see paragraph 5.9.3). Is the cylindrical wave a one dimensional wave? My question arises because it depends only on $r$, but at the same time, it has a 2D development.
2. Is it possible to write an equation using as spatial variable a vector?

$$\nabla^{2}{\eta}-\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2{\eta}}{\partial t^2}=0 
    $$

3. Solving the Eq. above do we obtain this wave?

$$\eta(\vec{x},t)=E e ^{-i\omega t - i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}$$

I saw sometimes the dot product in the exponent, but I am not sure if this come from the use of the vector in the differential equation showed above.

Comment: @GiorgioP Sorry, I substituted the diffusion word with development ( I mis-used this word because I use it in my own language to visualise the concept). I hope it is more correct.

Comment: @J.Delaney I corrected using a laplacian now

Comment: (2) is only possible (at least to me) if $\vec{x}$ is some vector function of $x,y,z$. If you treat it as a constant vector or $x\hat{x}$, the Laplacian term will be 0 and $\eta(x,t)$ would be a linear function of time.

Comment: @MichaelM I don't understand your point, sorry!